# convert list of decimals to hexidecimals without getting truncated

Tags: python

I have a text file with a list of numbers that look like this

1. 295147905179352825855
2. 295147905179352825856
3. 295147905179352825857
4. 295147905179352825858

I'm trying to convert that list into hexidecimal numbers that look like this but all I get is 'truncated numbers. How do I convert that list to look like this?

1. 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffff
2. 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000
3. 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000001
4. 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000002

The output in terminal when converting is like "fcccccccca" and says "truncated over 20 digit" (I'm paraphrasing). I'm trying to get a 64 character hex.

Comment: Please include your code and show what you mean by 'truncated numbers'.

Comment: `format(295147905179352825855, "0100x")`.  I haven't actually counted how many digits you've got, but does a hundred digits.

Comment: I think it is important to know what version of Python you are operating with. That may affect the precision of the `int` type, for example. Your decimal values are very large (in the 64-bit range) so this is why I think it's important to know.

Comment: @beny Floating point numbers have complicated precision, for integers it's basically just width and that's dynamic and effectively unlimited for the `int` type in Python 3. It never overflows (apart from silly examples where the integer no longer fits in memory, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to convert large integers to hexadecimal strings, zero-padded to always show the full 256-bit hexadecimal representations:

```
n = 295147905179352825855

result = '{:0{}x}'.format(n, 64)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffff
```

Or if you prefer f-string notation:

```
result = f'{n:0{64}x}'
```